# Jumping to the next chapter in a document

Tags: navigation

What would be a good interaction for moving to the next chapter in a document? I am thinking about relatively long text chapters. I'm hoping the user could first skim through chapters and look at the title/poem/image displayed at the beginning of each chapter, then use `PgDn/PgUp` to find the right spot within the chapter, and finally use `arrow keys` to navigate line by line. Perhaps `PgDn/PgUp with some modifier key` would work for jumping to the beginning of previous/next chapter. Is there some standard way of doing such interaction?

What about touch controls? Is there some way that is typically used with touch controls for scrolling to the next chapter? I could of course provide a table of contents but that wouldn't support rapidly skimming through chapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question actually touches upon a number of distinct problems, so I'll give a brief answer to each sub-problem you raise.

### Navigating to any chapter quickly

If the user has a wide enough viewport, you can have a sidebar that scrolls with the page. Wikipedia uses this approach nowadays.

[image: Screenshot Wikipedia: "European Rock Pipit"]

On smaller screens, you'll likely need to put this into an icon which the user then can summon.

If you have a deeper structure, you also can have *two* sidebars with content, one for the stuff that happens on the current page, and another which puts this page in context with other chapters. This is a common-ish setup for help centers:

[image: screenshot vue community: "Build tools"]

NB: You should avoid nesting things too deeply in just one menu; see https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/148020/164315 for more.

### Navigating to the next chapter

If you have your users go through your content sequentially, good ol' next/previous buttons do the job.

[image: gitbook example]

The example here is quite prominent and rich, which *probably* is better suited for the navigation buttons near the footer of the page, if you were to put something right next to the title of the page, just using a simple "Next/Previous" or maybe even "← / →" buttons may suffice.

### Expected inputs for navigation

The most common interaction you'll see on your page is the humble scroll wheel. It's not the fastest, but it's the tool people are most familiar with. Using mouse and scrollwheel only, very long pages become exhausting pretty quickly. Having reasonably short sub-chapters or otherwise navigable anchor points in your content which get shown in a sidebar and can be clicked on is helpful.

For keyboard navigation, the typical navigation keys are indeed the most used. To switch to the next chapter, I've *sometimes* seen just right/left arrow keys, but most commonly just tabbing to the next/previous buttons which are on the page. Browsers use Alt+Left/Right to navigate to the previous/next page (granted - in history, not relative to the content), using some key modifier on arrow keys might be appropriate.

### Touch controls

The same principles as scrollwheel/mouse navigation apply, except that you now have to increase the spacing between interactable elements as fingers are quite a lot less precise than a mouse cursor. Scrolling will be replaced by swiping, which gets tiring very quickly, so again, having reasonably short sub-chapters which can be accessed by tapping on it in a sidebar (or an openable Table of Contents-panel) is helpful.

### Supporting skimming

In addition to having enough sub-chapters and paragraph breaks, it can be helpful to already annotate or highlight important parts of your content.

In the following example, a chapter about "Art as practice: theories about symbolic acting", the text comes to talk about Huizinger's [homo ludens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_Ludens), and it already has the key word you'd be looking for during skimming in the margin. The book does this all the way through, typically once or twice per paragraph.

[image: Fauser chapter IV excerpt]

An alternative approach is to highlight the key words in the text (with a different background color, or by making it bold).

---

All of the above just are surface level examples on how this can be handled. Some of these sub-problems may warrant a question on their own.

Comment: Makes sense. I imagine left/right swipe could be used instead of arrow keys, for previous/next chapter on a touch screen.